# how to handle form authentication in IE7&IE8

Tags: asp.net

Hi I am using IE7 and IE8 browser for running web appliction. I have login in the web application go on the next page. if have copy the url of the next page, and open new browser and paste url, then open directly next page. I mean my form authentication is not working. please help how to handle this issue.

Comment: I like how you're blaming IE for this

Comment: Rephrase your question, it makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know enough about asp.net to give exact code, but your login page should create a new session if it isn't already created.
When the logic behind the authentication form verifies the username/password, it should set a session variable to mark the user as logged in.
Pages which require login should then check for that session variable, and redirect to the login page if not set.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I have done all these thing on the page load. I mean check sessiion null on the page load but problem is in IE7 and 8 session main in different browser on the same machine.

Comment: @Aman - forms authentication is done by a cookie stored in the `browser` (unless you create a persistent one). So if you log in with IE8, then open say IE7, you are not automatically logged in. This has nothing to do with IE, it's how cookie-based authentication works.